# 'readline/keymaps.h' file not found

Tags: macos, go, readline, apple-m1

I'm trying to run a golang binary that uses readline on mac and it gives me an error like this:

```
# github.com/bobappleyard/readline
../../../../../../../pkg/mod/github.com/bobappleyard/readline@v0.0.0-20150707195538-7e300e02d38e/readline.go:45:10: fatal error: 'readline/keymaps.h' file not found
#include <readline/keymaps.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I followed instructions placed under github page [here](https://github.com/bobappleyard/readline) of that binding to install readline and mac Command Line Tools without any success.

Comment: we can only help you with your code not with a problem in a specific libray, you should open an issue on the libraries github page

Comment: I don't think this is problem with library. It's problem with mac os not seeing those header files

Comment: Uhm, i done some research and probably is because is a m1, see if this helps https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1691 . since i don't have a mac m1, i can't help with more code or solution, this theoretic solution.

Comment: I think would be the best, try reach the folks from that lib and see if is compatible with mac m1. since looks like it uses CGO.

Comment: Okay guys I managed to solve this issue by changing CFLAGS and LDFLAGS in the package. Like this :

#cgo darwin CFLAGS: -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include
#cgo darwin LDFLAGS: -L/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/lib

This is more like workaround but works brilliantly for my current needs